# Transition Manager delayed transition not working with multiple views in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-animation, slide, android-transitions

I am using transition manager to animate layout with bottom and top slide gravity. Top view transition animation is working perfectly but bottom view animation is not happening. Have a look at the code:

```
private void showImageOptions () {
    Transition transitionBottom, transitionTop;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        transitionTop = new Slide(Gravity.TOP);
        transitionBottom = new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        transitionTop.setDuration(500);
        transitionTop.addTarget(imageNameLayout);
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootLayout, transitionTop);
        transitionBottom.setDuration(500);
        transitionBottom.addTarget(constraintOptions);
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootLayout, transitionBottom);
    }
    if (imageNameLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        imageNameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        constraintOptions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } 
}
```